# How to install WinUSB driver through code

Tags: node.js, windows, libusb, winusb

I don't want the client to do an extra WinUSB installation for my node.js software. How can I install the WinUSB driver through code or there is an alternative to skip it?

Comment: WinUSB is part of Windows. It doesn't need and cannot be installed separately. Do you mean to install the WinUSB driver for a specific USB device?

Comment: Yes, Basically I am using a thermal printer in my node project and want to send ESC/POS commands but that requires me to install WinUSB for that printer. 
I can manually do it using Zadig but this is not a proper solution for my end users. @Codo

Comment: The best option would be if the printer implemented MS OS Descriptors. Then the WinUSB driver would be installed automatically. But I guess you can't change the printer. The next option is to us wdi-simple.exe. It's basically the command line version of Zadig (see https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi). You can also create a .inf file for the device and the use Windows APIs to run the installation. But I'm not familiar with the last option.